# Controller to view not passing in cs market place magento

Tags: magento

I am using cs market place magento I have created new function in VendorController.php but its not going to the Controller to view not passing, I am using this extension http://cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/marketplace-basic

```
public function leadsAction() {

        echo "hi";

        exit;
        if(!$this->_getSession()->getVendorId()) return;
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('csmarketplace/vendor_dashboard')
        );
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('csmarketplace')->__('Leads'));
        $navigationBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('csmarketplace_vendor_navigation');
        if ($navigationBlock) {
            $navigationBlock->setActive('csmarketplace/vendor/leadsview');
        }
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(true);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Vendor profile View page
     */
    public function leadsviewAction() {
        if(!$this->_getSession()->getVendorId()) return;
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('csmarketplace')->__('Vendor Leads View'));
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(true);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<!--
/**
 * CedCommerce
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 *
 * @category    Ced
 * @package     Ced_CsMarketplace
 * @author      CedCommerce Core Team <coreteam@cedcommerce.com>
 * @copyright   Copyright CedCommerce (http://cedcommerce.com/)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ced_CsMarketplace>
            <version>0.0.21</version>
            <release_version>0.1.28</release_version>
            <author>CedCommerce Core Team (coreteam@cedcommerce.com)</author>
        </Ced_CsMarketplace>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <csmarketplace>/csmarketplace/</csmarketplace>
        </secure_url>
        <routers>
            <csmarketplace>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ced_CsMarketplace</module>
                    <frontName>csmarketplace</frontName>
                </args>
            </csmarketplace>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <ced_vendor>
                    <file>ced/csmarketplace/vendor.xml</file>
                </ced_vendor>
                <csmarketplace>
                    <file>ced/csmarketplace/csmarketplace.xml</file>
                </csmarketplace>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <csmarketplace>
                    <files>
                        <default>Ced_CsMarketplace.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </csmarketplace>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <csmarketplace after="Mage_Adminhtml">Ced_CsMarketplace</csmarketplace>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <csmarketplace>
                    <files>
                        <default>Ced_CsMarketplace.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </csmarketplace>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <csmarketplace>
                    <file>ced/csmarketplace.xml</file>
                </csmarketplace>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
             <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Catalog_Product_Save_Before>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>saveVproductData</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Catalog_Product_Save_Before>
               </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <csmarketplace_feed_start>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>preDispatch</method>
                    </csmarketplace_feed_start>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <layout_load_before_cedcommerce>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                    </layout_load_before_cedcommerce>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <csmarketplace_rewrite_shop_url>
                <from><![CDATA[/\/vendor-shop\/(.*)/i]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[csmarketplace/vshops/view/shop_url/$1/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </csmarketplace_rewrite_shop_url>
        </rewrite>
        <helpers>
            <csmarketplace>
                <class>Ced_CsMarketplace_Helper</class>
            </csmarketplace>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <csmarketplace>
                <class>Ced_CsMarketplace_Block</class>
            </csmarketplace>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                  <catalog_product_created>Ced_CsMarketplace_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Created</catalog_product_created>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <category>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Vproducts_Category</category>
                    <layer>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Vshop_Layer</layer>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <layout>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Layout</layout>
                    <design_package>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Design_Package</design_package>
                    <store>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Core_Store</store>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <config_data>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Adminhtml_Config_Data</config_data>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
            <csmarketplace>
                <class>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>csmarketplace_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </csmarketplace>
            <csmarketplace_mysql4>
                <class>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <vendor>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor</table>
                    </vendor>
                    <vendor_form>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_form_attribute</table>
                    </vendor_form>
                    <address>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_address</table>
                    </address>
                    <vproducts>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_products</table>
                    </vproducts>
                    <vproducts_status>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_products_status</table>
                    </vproducts_status>
                    <vorders>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_sales_order</table>
                    </vorders>
                    <vpayment>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_payments</table>
                    </vpayment>
                    <vsettings>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_settings</table>
                    </vsettings>
                    <vshop>
                        <table>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_shop</table>
                    </vshop>
                </entities>
            </csmarketplace_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <csmarketplace_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ced_CsMarketplace</module>
                    <class>Ced_CsMarketplace_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </csmarketplace_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_massDelete>
                <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_MassDelete>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>deleteMassVproductData</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_MassDelete>
               </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_massDelete>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_delete>
                <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Delete>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>deleteVproductData</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Delete>
               </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_delete>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_massStatus>
                 <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_MassStatus>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>saveStatusChange</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_MassStatus>
               </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_massStatus>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save>
                <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Action_Attribute_Save>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>saveVproductAttributesData</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Action_Attribute_Save>
               </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save>
             <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_customer_delete>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Customer_Delete>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>deleteVendor</method>
                    </Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Customer_Delete>
                </observers>
             </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_customer_delete>
             <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_customer_massDelete>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Customer_MassDelete>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>massDeleteVendor</method>
                    </Ced_CsMarketplace_Controller_Action_Postdispatch_Adminhtml_Customer_MassDelete>
                </observers>
             </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_customer_massDelete> 
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Customer_Register_Success>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>VendorRegistration</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Customer_Register_Success>
               </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
            <sales_quote_item_set_product>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Sales_Quote_Item_Set_Product>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>salesQuoteItemSetVendorId</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Sales_Quote_Item_Set_Product>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_item_set_product>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Sales_Convert_Quote_To_Order>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>setVendorSalesOrder</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Sales_Convert_Quote_To_Order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
            <!-- <checkout_submit_all_after>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Checkout_Submit_All_After>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>checkoutSubmitAllAfter</method>
                    </Ced_CsMarketplace_Checkout_Submit_All_After>
                </observers>
            </checkout_submit_all_after> -->
            <order_cancel_after>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Order_Cancel_After>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>orderCancelAfter</method>
                    </Ced_CsMarketplace_Order_Cancel_After>
                </observers>
            </order_cancel_after>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Order_Creditmemo_Refund>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>orderCreditmemoRefund</method>
                    </Ced_CsMarketplace_Order_Creditmemo_Refund>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
            <core_config_data_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <Ced_CsMarketplace_Core_Config_Data_Save_Before>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>coreConfigSaveAfter</method>
                    </Ced_CsMarketplace_Core_Config_Data_Save_Before>
                </observers>
            </core_config_data_save_before>
            <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Sales_Order_Invoice_Save_After>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>changeOrderPaymentState</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Sales_Order_Invoice_Save_After>
               </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <customer_save_before>
                <observers>
                   <Ced_CsMarketplace_Customer_Save_Before>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>csmarketplace/observer</class>
                      <method>setVendorEmail</method>
                   </Ced_CsMarketplace_Customer_Save_Before>
               </observers>
            </customer_save_before>
        </events>

        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_item>
                <vendor_id>
                    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                </vendor_id>
            </sales_convert_quote_item>
            <sales_convert_order_item>
                <vendor_id>
                    <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
                    <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
                    <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
                    <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
                </vendor_id>
            </sales_convert_order_item>
        </fieldsets>
        <template>
            <email>
                <ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_confirmed_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor account confirmed</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/account_confirmed.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_confirmed_template>
                <ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_rejected_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor account rejected</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/account_rejected.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_rejected_template>
                <ced_csmarketplace_vendor_shop_enabled_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor shop enabled</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/shop_enabled.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_csmarketplace_vendor_shop_enabled_template>
                <ced_csmarketplace_vendor_shop_disabled_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor shop disabled</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/shop_disabled.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_csmarketplace_vendor_shop_disabled_template>
                <ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_deleted_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor account deleted</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/account_deleted.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_deleted_template>
                <ced_vproducts_general_product_approved_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor - Product approved notification</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/product_approved.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_vproducts_general_product_approved_template>
                <ced_vproducts_general_product_rejected_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor - Product rejected notification</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/product_rejected.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_vproducts_general_product_rejected_template>
                <ced_vproducts_general_product_deleted_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor - Product deleted notification</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/product_deleted.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_vproducts_general_product_deleted_template>
                <ced_vorders_general_order_new_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor - New Order</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/order_new.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_vorders_general_order_new_template>
                <ced_vorders_general_order_cancel_template translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor - Cancel Order</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/order_cancel.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_vorders_general_order_cancel_template>
                <ced_vdebug_report translate="label" module="csmarketplace">
                    <label>Vendor - Debug Report</label>
                    <file>ced_csmarketplace/vdebug_report.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </ced_vdebug_report>
            </email>
        </template>
        <ced_csmarketplace>
            <vendor>
                <groups>
                    <general>
                        <model>csmarketplace/vendor_group_general</model>
                    </general>
                </groups>
                <rates>
                    <percentage>
                        <model>csmarketplace/vendor_rate_percentage</model>
                    </percentage>
                    <fixed>
                        <model>csmarketplace/vendor_rate_fixed</model>
                    </fixed>
                </rates>
                <payment_methods>
                    <cheque>*</cheque>
                    <paypal>*</paypal>
                    <banktransfer>*</banktransfer>
                </payment_methods>
            </vendor>
            <vproducts>
                <types>
                    <simple>*</simple>
                    <downloadable>*</downloadable>
                    <virtual>*</virtual>
                </types>
            </vproducts>
        </ced_csmarketplace>
    </global>
    <default>
        <!-- <cedcore>
            <extensions_groups>
                <extensions><![CDATA[<a class="button" href="http://cedcommerce.com/store/" id="cedcore_extensions_groups_extensions" style="text-decoration: none; " title="Checkout CedCommerce Website">Checkout CedCommerce Website</a><style>#cedcore_extensions_groups_extensions td.scope-label {display: none;}</style>]]></extensions>
            </extensions_groups>
        </cedcore> -->
        <!-- <style>
        #cedcore_extensions_groups_extensions td.scope-label {display: none;}
        </style> -->
        <ced_csmarketplace>
            <general>
                <activation>1</activation>
                <enable_registration>1</enable_registration>
                <confirmation>1</confirmation>
                <vendor_groups_active>0</vendor_groups_active>
                <use_in_vendorpanel>0</use_in_vendorpanel>
            </general>
            <vendor>
                <group>general</group>
                <status>new</status>
                <email_identity>general</email_identity>
                <account_confirmed_template>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_confirmed_template</account_confirmed_template>
                <account_rejected_template>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_rejected_template</account_rejected_template>
                <account_deleted_template>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_account_deleted_template</account_deleted_template>
                <shop_enabled_template>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_shop_enabled_template</shop_enabled_template>
                <shop_disabled_template>ced_csmarketplace_vendor_shop_disabled_template</shop_disabled_template>
                <vendor_theme>ced/default</vendor_theme>
                <vendor_logo_src>images/logo.gif</vendor_logo_src>
                <vendor_logo_alt>Vendor Panel</vendor_logo_alt>
                <vendor_footer_text><![CDATA[&copy; 2015 <strong>CedCommerce</strong>. All Rights Reserved.]]></vendor_footer_text>
                <theme_css></theme_css>
            </vendor>
        </ced_csmarketplace>
        <ced_vproducts>
            <general>
                <activation>1</activation>
                <confirmation>1</confirmation>
                <type>simple,downloadable,virtual</type>
                <limit>100</limit>
                <category_mode>0</category_mode>
                <email_identity>general</email_identity>
                <product_approved_template>ced_vproducts_general_product_approved_template</product_approved_template>
                <product_rejected_template>ced_vproducts_general_product_rejected_template</product_rejected_template>
                <product_deleted_template>ced_vproducts_general_product_deleted_template</product_deleted_template>
            </general>
            <downloadable_config>
                <link_formats>zip,rar,pdf,doc</link_formats>
                <sample_formats>jpg,jpeg,png,gif,pdf,rar</sample_formats>
            </downloadable_config>
        </ced_vproducts>
        <ced_vorders>
            <general>
                <!-- <vorders_mode>0</vorders_mode> -->
                <order_email_enable>1</order_email_enable>
                <order_cancel_email_enable>1</order_cancel_email_enable>
                <email_identity>general</email_identity>
                <order_new_template>ced_vorders_general_order_new_template</order_new_template>
                <order_cancel_template>ced_vorders_general_order_cancel_template</order_cancel_template>                
            </general>
        </ced_vorders>
        <ced_vpayments>
            <general>
                <online>0</online>
                <payment_approval>0</payment_approval>
                <commission_mode>percentage</commission_mode>
                <commission_fee>10</commission_fee>
            </general>
        </ced_vpayments>
        <ced_vshops>
            <general>
                <logo_image_width>175</logo_image_width>
                <logo_image_height>150</logo_image_height>
                <banner_image_width>668</banner_image_width>
                <banner_image_height>150</banner_image_height>
                <grid_image_width>135</grid_image_width>
                <grid_image_height>135</grid_image_height>
                <list_image_width>135</list_image_width>
                <list_image_height>135</list_image_height>
                <vshoppage_about>CEDCOMMERCE is a leading solution provider for web based applications. The Company has been promoted by highly experienced professionals dedicated to provide high quality IT solutions. We provide values to the product with applied quality process. We define, design and deliver IT solutions to our clients which help them to become front runner up in there domain. With CEDCOMMERCE, clients are assured of a transparent business partner, world-class processes, speed of execution and the power to stretch their IT budget by leveraging the global delivery model that CEDCOMMERCE pioneered.
Our services includes a range of preliminary to enterprise level solutions. CEDCOMMERCE provides consultancy, design, development, maintenance and customization for your existing business applications. </vshoppage_about>
                <vshoppage_banner></vshoppage_banner>
                <vshoppage_vendor_placeholder></vshoppage_vendor_placeholder>
                <vshoppage_banner_placeholder></vshoppage_banner_placeholder>
                <vshoppage_title>CsMarketplace</vshoppage_title>
                <vshoppage_top_title>CsMarketplace</vshoppage_top_title>
                <vshoppage_top_enabled>1</vshoppage_top_enabled>
                <vshoppage_vendor_title>I am a Vendor</vshoppage_vendor_title>
                <vshoppage_vendor_enabled>1</vshoppage_vendor_enabled>
                <vshoppage_banner_image_width>800</vshoppage_banner_image_width>
                <vshoppage_banner_image_height>200</vshoppage_banner_image_height>
            </general>
        </ced_vshops>
        <ced_vlogs>
            <general>
                <process_file>vendor_process.log</process_file>
                <exception_file>vendor_exception.log</exception_file>
            </general>
        </ced_vlogs>
        <system>
            <csmarketplace>
                <feed_url>cedcommerce.com/notification.rss</feed_url>
                <popup_url>widgets.magentocommerce.com/notificationPopup</popup_url>
                <severity_icons_url>widgets.magentocommerce.com/%s/%s.gif</severity_icons_url>
                <frequency>72</frequency>
                <last_update>0</last_update>
            </csmarketplace>
            <license>
                <use_https>0</use_https>
                <license_url>adminhtml/adminhtml_license/index/</license_url>
                <activate_url>cedcommerce.com/licensing/validate/</activate_url>
            </license>
        </system>
        <cedcore>
            <feeds_group>
                <feeds>INFO,PROMO,UPDATE_RELEASE,NEW_RELEASE,INSTALLED_UPDATE</feeds>
            </feeds_group>
        </cedcore>
        <ced_vseo>
            <general>
                <marketplace_url_suffix>.html</marketplace_url_suffix>
                <marketplace_url_key>vendor-shop</marketplace_url_key>
            </general>
        </ced_vseo>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: How are you trying to access this function?

Comment: http://example.com/csmarketplace/vendor/leadsview/

Comment: Its  passing to function but its not going to vendor folder to leads view

Comment: Can you update the question with config.xml file? and if you are debugging leadsviewAction then why did you put echo exit in leadsAction?

Comment: i just put for texting whether its passing or not

Comment: Updated with config.xml